# Which method is better to store related data in table(s)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, optimization

I have simple but important question about storing data in database.
Assume a website has **100,000 users**. and these users can be friend with each other.
which method of storage is ideal

**Method A:**

1. make a `friends` field in USERS table. Type: TEXT
2. save all friends IDs in it, concat them with a `,` . example: friends of USER 1 : 2,3,4,5,6,...
3. *the worst status*: all users are friend with each other which each user has a FULL TEXT friend field. AND so in php side, should separate this field with `,` delimiter which requires some process.

**Method B:**

1. make a `friendship` table

   ```
   +------+---------------------+  
   | uid  | friend_id           |  
   +------+---------------------+  
   | 1    | 2                   |  
   | 1    | 3                   |    
   | 1    | 4                   |  
   | 1    | 5                   |
   +------+---------------------+
   ```
2. as you see above, for each friend of a user, I should insert a new row to the table.
3. *the worst status:* all users are friend with each other so 100,000 x 100,000 ( not sure ) rows should store in the table.

Which one of these two methods are ok? performance and optimization.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Method A is totally horrible. Don't do that to yourself.

Comment: Method A is introducing a string into your database and databases generally don't handle strings/arrays very well (can't join on them, hard to bring out a list of friends...etc).  Method B is by far preferable, 1 row per friend relation.  Funny enough, to read the data in method A, you pretty much have to convert it to what method B already stores it as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method B** is prefered, according to [normalization theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

**Method A** will have following issues:

1. Slower, as string search in most cases take more time, while integer comparison is faster.
2. It would be a problem to maintain referental integrity. For example, if you delete any user, which is friend to any, you should delete it from their *friend* fields. It will take a lot of time, because DBMS will have to perform a huge count of string processing operations.
3. It might be a problem to build complex queries in this case.

And it is only a top of the iceberg of problems. It will cause total database speed slowdown, if user table will be in the middle of your database schema (as it oftenly happends). I mean, if it will be linked to a lot of other tables.

You may restore **Method A** representation easily from **Method B**:

```
SELECT
    `User`.`uid` as `user`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`Friendship`.`friend_id`) as `friends`
FROM
    `User` LEFT JOIN `Friendship` ON `User`.`uid` = `Friendship`.`uid`
GROUP BY
    `User`.`uid`
```

However, it might be a complicated task to get **Method B** representation, starting from **Method A**. Just think about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to query or link to it: Method B, no question. make sure you make it an unsigned type and put an index on it. TEXT fields will not be read in memory, but swapped to disk, it is always slow and should be avoided when not really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

option B is what you should choose, and put two indexes, one for each column of friendship table.

all CRUD operations on both tables will be faster

the A one obliges you to perform searches by combining LIKE and OR operators, it may go very slow

Answer (score 1):

The usual way would be to your **Method B**

In Database-design you try to one Information per field. Storing a huge String with all friends would be *unclean and irritating*. Also, every time a friendship is created/erased, you need to *alter your table at two different places* which is very bad too (in terms of maintenance).
Also, doing the whole string exploding, searching etc. *takes much longer* then searching the Table via SQL.

So all in all, Method B is:

1. More Clean and normalized
2. Easier to maintain
3. Faster
4. more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Your **Method B** is the correct approach. It is fast and flexible.

Important notes:

- You should create a `UNIQUE` index on the 2 columns combined, in the `friendship` table. That way, you will ensure that duplicates are not occurring in that table. Additionally, you do not even need to have a separate Identity column in this case (unless you need it for other reasons) - the composite key itself could be the PK for this table.
- Create a `FOREIGN KEY` from each of these 2 columns into the ID column of your `friends` table. This will help ensure referential integrity in your system.

I would also recommend that the 2 sides of the relation be represented in 2 rows, i.e. 1 -> 2 and 2-> 1 should be on separate rows. This approach gives more advantages:

- Your logic to "locate all friends of Person 1" will have to look only in column 1 (not both columns)
- Additional columns could be added later to show things like "friendship status" which will be different in the 2 rows, e.g. "invitation sent" (in the 1->2 row) or "invitation received" (in the 2->1 row).